# What is the best way to determine if a script is being run by cron in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.4

I need a piece of code to execute differently if it's being run by cron, what is the best way to check programmatically that cron is the execution source?

I know that it can be done by checking for website or session being unavailable, but I'm concerned these seem a bit hacky.  I'm wondering if there's some clean isRunningFromCron kind of function that abstracts this to dependency-inject, or if the aforementioned hacks would be robust enough that I'm being over-cautious.

Thanks!

EDIT:
It may actually not be possible to use the current store ID check in my circumstance, as the script is otherwise being run from adminhtml, which I think would also have a store_id of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically you should be able to use the area code for your needs. Take the example of the `vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Console/Command/TaskRunnerCommand.php` class which uses  `Magento\Framework\App\State` to handle the current area:

```php
try {
    $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_CRONTAB);
} catch (LocalizedException $e) {
    if ($this->state->getAreaCode() != Area::AREA_CRONTAB) {
        $output->writeln(__(
           sprintf('Warning: command running in an unexpected state (%s)', $this->state->getAreaCode())
        )->getText());
   }
}
```

So you could set the area as crontab for the part that is meant for your cron to execute.

More on Magento areas here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_and_areas.html#magento-area-types

Good luck!

Comment: Area::AREA_CRONTAB is exactly what I was looking for, fantastic, thanks!

Comment: you are most welcome! cheers!